# Error while connecting SQL Server management studio 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have installed SQL Server 2008 management studio. When I connect, it shows an error. Also when I go to the SQL Server configuration manager and click on SQL Server SERVER services, this message is shown:

> There are no items in list to view

No connections are found in the SQL Server configuration manager while my local network is connected.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the exact error you get when you try to connect ?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you only installed the management studio and not the actual database engine.  You need to connect to a remote SQL Server instance not to your local machine as your local machine doesn't appear to have a SQL Server instance installed.

If you need your own database engine installed you'll need to run through the installer again and install the database engine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the TCP/IP is enabled or not.

to check this open Server configuration manager --> Sql Server network configuration --protocols for 'sql server instance name' --> TCP/IP.

if it is disabled enable it.

Comment: TCP isn't used to connect to a local instance.  Shared memory is used, and is enabled by default.